# C# NUnit Mock Database Setup to test embedded SQL

Tags: c#, sql, .net, nunit, .net-4.8

Project Framework: .NetFramework (Not .NetCore)

UnitTest Framework: NUnit 3.13.0

Project construction sample:

**Program.cs:**

```
class Program
{
      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
            SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=serverName;Database=dbName;Trusted_Connection=True;");
            connection.open();
     
            TestProcess _process = new TestProcess();
            _process.Run(connection);

            connection.close();

      }
}
```

**TestProcess.cs:**

```
class TestProcess
{
      public void Run(SqlConnection connection)
      {
            List<StudentModel> students = GetFromDb(connection);
            //Do something with students
      }

      public void GetFromDb(SqlConnection connection)
      {
            List<StudentModel> students = new List<StudentModel>();
            DataTabel table = new DataTable();
            //This could be a view or a table
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM dbName.vwStudents", connection)
            {
                  using (SqlReader dataRead = command.ExecuteReader())
                  {
                        tabel.load(dataRead);
                  }
            }
            foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
            {
                  students.Add(new Student(row));
            }
            return students;
      }
}
```

PS: The code works fine, this is just a sample, so ignore any problems you see with it

So, I am trying to write unit tests for this kind of a setup. Lets say I am writing unit tests for the GetFromDb() function. Is there a way I could mockup the database without actually querying the db. Or maybe I could create a facade. I am not using EFCore to create a context and use facade directly.

I understand that using embedded sql is not the best way, but this is probably the easiest approach for my project. I already moved the sqlconnection out to the main() to make it a little better. Anyway, what is the best way to unitTest this setup without touching the DB. Is that even possible?
Also, I am not keen on redoing the project but if you think moving a few things around will help me write better tests, I am all ears.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can only mock abstract dependencies and not concrete types. Meaning you should be passing an interface instead. I would point out that you are not following SOLID principles hence there will be difficulties in testing your code. Ideally you should test code that fetches the data (student service) while the actual fetching of records are abstracted (database/file/etc.). These principles isn't something you'll learn just by reading a comment or two. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah, I am familiar with SOLID principles. This was an older code base that I just refactored, and didn't consider testing when I wrote the code. I get your point though. I will consider maybe separating the sql calls and create an interface for it. Thank you